# latex accents in two letters not in math environment

Tags: math-mode, accents, dictionaries

[image: Concise Oxford Dictionary Pronunciation]

The pronunciation given in Concise Oxford Dictionary (before 7th edition) is directly with entry words, as shown in above picture. How to get accents in two letters not in math environment?

Comment: The tie over two letters can be input directly with `\t`, e.g. `f\t{ar}`.

Answer (score 3):

As campa noted, `\t` handles one of the cases.  For the others, I provide `\twofer{<accent>}{<two-lowercase-letter-string>`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\twofer[2]{\@firstoftwo#2\makebox[0pt]{\scalebox{1.8}[.95]{#1{}}}\@secondoftwo#2}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\t{or}

\twofer{\u}{oo}

\twofer{\=}{ur}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many tks for your answer. \usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{LiberationSerif-Bold} The solution is just available to CMU Font? When I change default font to Liberation Serif or other fonts, it produced a queer result...

Comment: @Marcus The two numbers, `1.8` and `.95` may need adjustment with the font.  The former is a horizontal stretch, the latter is both a vertical stretch but also a vertical positioner.  I don't have access to the font you mention to tweak it for you.

Answer (score 3):

You might do like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp,graphicx}

\newcommand{\bbar}[1]{%
  \leavevmode\vbox{%
    \offinterlineskip
    \halign{%
      \hfil##\hfil\cr
      \={}\kern-.4em\={}\cr
      \noalign{\kern-1ex}
      #1\cr
    }%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\revt}[1]{%
  \leavevmode
  \vphantom{\t{#1}}%
  \smash{\vbox{%
    \offinterlineskip
    \halign{%
      \hfil##\hfil\cr
      \scalebox{1}[-1]{\capitalnewtie{}}\cr
      \noalign{\kern.1ex}
      #1\cr
    }%
  }}%
}

\begin{document}

\t{ar} \bbar{ar} \revt{ar}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many tks for your answer. \usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{LiberationSerif-Bold} The solution is just available to CMU Font? When I change default font to Liberation Serif or other fonts, it produced a queer result...

Comment: @Marcus Usage with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX is a very different story

Comment: @egreg Apologies for digging an old post of yours. Is it possible to adapt your `\revt` code to work in math mode?

Comment: @M.G. I'm not sure your readers would understand the meaning.

Comment: @egreg: Well, I am looking for a 'wide' version of the breve accent in math mode, similar to `\widehat` or `\widetilde` (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/444317/how-to-create-wide-breve-accent) and a user there referred me to this post. In theory at least it looks like something that would do the job.

Comment: @M.G. I saw your question: there is no typographically sound way to get a wide breve accent.

Comment: @egreg: I see. Is there any reasonale alternative then? I am looking for a closure operator that's similar in spirit but different than 'widebar', 'widetilde', 'widehat' and 'widecheck' to avoid notational overloading.