# How to create wide breve accent?

Tags: math-mode, accents, width

I am in need of a 'wide breve' accent in math mode that can stretch a little bit like `\widetilde` and `\widehat` do. I have tried both suggestions from [Display a breve over several letters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/190996/display-a-breve-over-several-letters), but the first one is rather unsatisfactory for several reasons. The second one looks good on the picture, but *it does not work well with single letters*:

[image: deformed widebreve]

For convenience here is the code itself from the original post in the linked thread:

```
\makeatletter
\def\widebreve#1{\mathop{\vbox{\m@th\ialign{##\crcr\noalign{\kern\p@}%
  \brevefill\crcr\noalign{\kern0.1\p@\nointerlineskip}%
  $\hfil\displaystyle{#1}\hfil$\crcr}}}\limits}

\def\brevefill{$\m@th \setbox\z@\hbox{}%
 \hfill\scalebox{0.7}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{(}} \kern4pt $}
\makeatletter
```

I would like to have similarly nice wide breve as in this example

[image: Example]

that also works for single letters in math mode and is wider than mere `\breve{U}`. Think of `\widetilde{U}` or `\widehat{U}`. I would be happy if anyone knows how to fix it or has a better suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, could you please include an image of what you would like to achieve? Even a small photograph with your own sketch by hand.

Comment: @Sebastiano: yes, sorry, done. I used the same image as the OP from the linked thread.

Comment: @M.G. If I compile the code from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/195758/134574) the result is identical to the picture...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: you are correct, I just tried only the original code and it works as intended. So it must be my own preamble settings that interfere!

Comment: @M.G. There is anything here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376103/latex-accents-in-two-letters-not-in-math-environment

Comment: @Sebastiano: excellent find! These would work too.

Comment: @M.G. If you show us a compilable code that produces the wrong output we can find out what is causing this. Otherwise I'm afraid there's not much we can do...

Comment: @Sebastiano: thank you! I am trying to find out which part of my own settings interfere with the above code and then I will also try the code posted in the thread you linked.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: yes, of course, but let me first try to find where the problem is with my own settings. I would not like to bother the community with some trivial problem that I might be able to resolve on my own. If I find the problem, I will update my post with the cause, and if not, I will post my code.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: I found the issue, it's really silly and had nothing to do with my preamble. The problem is the code in question for 'widebreve' does not work well with single letter, which is why the OP from the linked thread used only 'breve' for single letters. So the question stands, but I've editted accordingly.

Comment: @Sebastiano: do you know how to make egreg's code from the thread you linked earlier work in math mode? At the moment it works only for natural language.

Comment: @M.G. You can use the chat to contact egreg.

Comment: @Sebastiano: I don't see the chat option at the moment, but I've 'pinged' him and hopefully he will respond.

Comment: @M.G. The direct link: https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=tex.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that Sabian's code works only for two characters, so here's my attempt to improve it:

> [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\def\widebreve{\mathpalette\wide@breve}
\def\wide@breve#1#2{\sbox\z@{$#1#2$}%
     \mathop{\vbox{\m@th\ialign{##\crcr
\kern0.08em\brevefill#1{0.8\wd\z@}\crcr\noalign{\nointerlineskip}%
                    $\hss#1#2\hss$\crcr}}}\limits}
\def\brevefill#1#2{$\m@th\sbox\tw@{$#1($}%
  \hss\resizebox{#2}{\wd\tw@}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\upshape(}}\hss$}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\(\widebreve{ONO}\) & \(A^{\widebreve{ONO}}\) & \(B^{A^{\widebreve{ONO}}}\) \\
\(\widebreve{ON}\)  & \(A^{\widebreve{ON}}\)  & \(B^{A^{\widebreve{ON}}}\) \\
\(\widebreve{U}\)   & \(A^{\widebreve{U}}\)   & \(B^{A^{\widebreve{U}}}\) \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The command works, in principle, with an arbitrary amount of characters. There are a few points, though, that require manual tuning. The line that says

```
\kern0.08em\brevefill#1{0.8\wd\z@}\crcr\noalign{\nointerlineskip}%
```

contains two adjustable parameters: `\kern0.08em` and `0.8\wd\z@`. The first is the horizontal space to be inserted to the left of the breve accent to make it look "more centered". The second (`0.8`) is the relative with of the accent relative to the accented characters.

Comment: There appears to be a problem when using your `\widebar{U}` in theorem-like environments with `\theoremstyle{italic}`. In environments having `\theoremstyle{normal}` everything works fine, though. For some reason the `italic` style does not go well with your code and produces a deformed breve accent like in the first picture in my post above.

Comment: @M.G. I fixed it. The accent is actually a rotated `(`, so in italic context, the `(` is italic, thus the "deformation". It was just necessary to enforce an upright font for the parenthesis.

Comment: Gotcha, everything works fine now. Thanks for the quick response!